# How do I set the width of the rowLabels column on matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

It seems code below should set the width of the column containing the row labels. Yet it only sets the other columns.

I've also tried passing a `colWidths` argument but the result is the same.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axis('tight')
ax.axis('off')
colLabels = ['ColA', 'ColB', 'ColC', 'ColD', 'ColE']
rowLabels = ['Row1', 'Row2', 'Row3', 'Row4']
dados = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
    [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],

]
table = ax.table(
    cellText=dados, loc='center', 
    colLabels=colLabels, 
    rowLabels=rowLabels,
    # `colWidths=[0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, ],` # <- same result
)
for cell in table.get_celld().values():
    cell.set_width(.15)
    print(cell.get_text().get_text()) # shows that the column is iterated through

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column containing the "Row" titles tries to automatically set the width. To stop this happening you can reset [`table._autoColumns`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v3.6.3/lib/matplotlib/table.py#L317) to an empty list, e.g.,:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axis('tight')
ax.axis('off')
colLabels = ['ColA', 'ColB', 'ColC', 'ColD', 'ColE']
rowLabels = ['Row1', 'Row2', 'Row3', 'Row4']
dados = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
    [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],

]
table = ax.table(
    cellText=dados, loc='center', 
    colLabels=colLabels, 
    rowLabels=rowLabels,
    # `colWidths=[0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, ],` # <- same result
)

table._autoColumns = []  # empty the _autoColumns

for cell in table.get_celld().values():
    cell.set_width(.15)
    print(cell.get_text().get_text()) # shows that the column is iterated through

plt.show()
```